# Spectrum of $(Mf)(t):=tf(t)$ for $f$ is a complex-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Let $X:=C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ be equipped with $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}:=sup_{t\in [0,1]}\vert f(t)\vert$ and define $M:X\to X$ by $(Mf)(t):=tf(t)$. Prove that the spectrum of $M$ is $\sigma(M)=[0,1]$

I solved this exercise but my solution is completely different than the one we got in the class. Is mine still correct?

**My solution:**

Assume there is some $\tilde{\lambda}\in [0,1]$ such that $\tilde{\lambda}\mathbb{1}-M$ is bijective. Then since $X$ is a Banach space by the inverse operator theorem $(\tilde{\lambda}\mathbb{1}-M)^{-1}$ is bounded. But this is not possible since $(\tilde{\lambda}\mathbb{1}-M)f(t)=(\tilde{\lambda}-t)f(t)$ and so its inverse diverges at $t=\tilde{\lambda}$.

**Solution from the class:**
Assume $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\backslash [0,1]$ and define $R_{\lambda}f(t):=\frac{1}{\lambda-t}f(t)$. By assumption $inf_{t\in[0,1]}\vert \lambda - t\vert >0$. Hence $C:=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\frac{1}{\lambda-t}<\infty$ is bounded. So $\Vert R_{\lambda}f\Vert_{\infty}=sup_t \vert \frac{1}{\lambda-t}f(t)\vert\leq C \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\Vert R_{\lambda}\Vert=\sup_f \frac{\Vert R_{\lambda}f\Vert_{\infty}}{\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}}\leq C$ hence $R_{\lambda}$ is bounded. Obviously $(\lambda \mathbb{1}-M)R_{\lambda}=R_{\lambda}(\lambda \mathbb{1}-M)=\mathbb{1}$ so $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}\backslash [0,1]$ $\lambda\mathbb{1}-M$ has an inverse.

Comment: The solution from the class is not complete, they only show that $\sigma(M)\subset [0,1]$. Your solution only shows that $[0,1]\subset \sigma(M)$.

Comment: Ah ok thank you @Mathematician42! But then both together me can conclude right? :)

Comment: Also, take care of notation, you write that $(\tilde{\lambda}1-M)=(\tilde{\lambda}-t)f(t)$, this is wrong, it should be $(\tilde{\lambda}1-M)f(t)=(\tilde{\lambda}-t)f(t)$. Together they form a solution. But can you be more specific as to why $(\tilde{\lambda}-M)$ is not invertible for $\tilde{\lambda}\in [0,1]$? You have the idea, but can you rigorously prove it?

Comment: @Mathematician42 ok ! ah sorry that was a tip-mistake. I though it is rigorous enough to say that the inverse diverges at $t=\tilde{\lambda}$. Isn't it?

Comment: Sure, I sometimes prefer more rigour, but this will do. As a fun exercise, do the same for the Hilbert space $X=L^2([0,1])$ with the usual norm.

Comment: Ok I will! Thank you @Mathematician42

Comment: To be precise, you have not shown why the inverse "diverge". Indeed I cannot think of a definition of that.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I've done it for $X=L^2([0,1])$. And I find that the point spectrum is also empty and the spectrum is equal to $[0,1]$ too. Is it right?

Comment: Correct, in fact the spectrum consists only of continuous spectrum. As you can see, Artic Char is not convinced by your argument of the non-invertibility of $(\tilde{\lambda}-M)$ for $\tilde{\lambda}\in [0,1]$. Convince him that you know why this is true.